# referenciar una propiedad o un método de un constructor, desde un método de un objeto literal, que está dentro del constructor

Tags: javascript, poo, scope

Hola quisiera saber cómo referenciar una propiedad o un método de un constructor, desde un método de un objeto literal, que se encuentra dentro del constructor.

esto es...

```
var MyObject = function () {


    this.aux = function() {console.log('1')}
    this.foo = {
        update: function() {
            // cómo puedo llamar a this.aux() desde aquí
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de @aldanux es buena, pero por si quieres otra alternativa:

```
var MyObject = function () {

    function aux(){
      console.log("hey");
    }

    this.aux = aux;

    this.foo = {
        update: function() {
            aux();
      }
    }
}
```

Declaras la funcion de aux, en una funcion privada del objeto, y puedes acceder a ella en cualquier punto del objeto, y luego solo la tienes que asígnar a aux, para que this.aux, tenga la misma funcionalidad.

Un saludo.

Comment: gracias a todos por su respuesta. ahora así puedo seguir aprendiendo . 1+

Answer (score 1):

El problema es la clave `this` dentro de la función `update`.

Solución: Pasa el `this` del objeto `MyObject` a una variable local.

```js
let MyObject = function () {
    
    let thisObj = this;
    
    this.aux = function() {console.log('1');}
    this.foo = {
        update: function() {
            thisObj.aux();
        }
    }
}
    
let miObjeto = new MyObject();
    
miObjeto.foo.update();
```

[+ Info sobre `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this)

*Actualizado tras editar la pregunta [original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/84409/1).*